# Inconsistency in SQLite-DB between Eclipse-project and SQLite Manager

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

I am developing a Java-application, which is using an SQLite-database. To have a better view of the data and to change the tables easier, I am using the Firefox plugin "SQLite Manager".

The sqlite-database is placed in my src-folder (src/db/db.sqlite).
If I open the database from that location, the database shows old entries.

Instead, I have a method in my code, which is reading all data from the table, and writing it into a .docx. Here I can see the data, I previously wrote into the table in another method.

It looked like Eclipse was locking the database-file somehow. 
Copying it to another location, and reopen it from there with the SQLite-Manager, still showed old entries.

Edit: Now I added another column to my table and deleted the content of the table with the SQLite Manager. If I export the content of my table to a .docx again, I get en empty .docx, which tells me that the database now is consistent again with what is shown in the SQLite Manager.

I didn't manage to find an answer to that behaviour in the web.
Does anyone know, why this happens?

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a solution. I will try this.

Comment: @cricket_007 You were right. Choosing it from the /bin-directory gave me the correct database.

Comment: If you post this as an answer, I would like to mark it as the top answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, your database is probably copied to the `bin/` directory because you've included it under the `src/` directory.

You should move your database file somewhere where you can [load it from the resource loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187043/add-sqlite-db-to-executable-jar-file) instead of referencing the direct filepath on your disk.